# Searching and Count records matching criteria in Django

Tags: django, search

I'd like to have a sorted list of certain database fields in my app e.g say year (where I'll have all records having a certain year tallied and the total displayed as in: 2009 (10), 2008(3) etc) then clicking on a certain year will display these records.

How should I do this?

**EDIT 1**

```
class Year(models.Model):
  year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

  def __unicode__(self):
     return unicode(self.year)

class CommonVehicle(models.Model):
  year = models.ForeignKey(Year)
  series = models.ForeignKey(Series)

  def __unicode__(self):
    name = ''+str(self.year)+" "+str(self.series)
    return name 

class Vehicle(models.Model):
   stock_number = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=False)
   vin = models.CharField(max_length=17, blank=False)
   common_vehicle = models.ForeignKey(CommonVehicle)

   def __unicode__(self):
     return self.stock_number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query for the summary list should look something like this (Django 1.1+ only):

```
from django.db.models import Count
Widget.objects.order_by('year').values('year').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

This will return a list of dictionaries, something like the following:

```
[{'count': 3, 'year': 2006}, {'count': 1, 'year': 2007}, {'count': 2, 'year': 2009}]
```

You can easily iterate through this in your template to generate your list of links:

```
{% for item in year_counts %}
  <li><a href="{% url year_view year=item.year %}">{{ item.year }} ({{ item.count }})</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Where "year_view" is a view you create up that accepts a "year" parameter and displays a filtered list of objects like:

```
Widget.objects.filter(year=year)
```

Comment: I've modified my models to be as shown in my edit above...now when I try the following code, I get a blank return: 
Vehicles.objects.order_by('common_vehicle__year__year').values('common_vehicle__year__year').aggregate(count=Count('id'))

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, it should be annotate, not aggregate. Fixed above.

Comment: thnx Carl...just one last quick question, can this work for other fields as well e.g. vehicle makes?

Comment: Great :)  thnx for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but you can count the number of objects in a filtered query simply by doing:

```
this_year = Widget.object.filter(you_date_field__year=2009).count()
```